# Change text aligment depending on the display width

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have 2 columns next to each other (col-md-6), which are displayed one below the other on small displays (col-sm-12).

The text in the 2nd column is displayed left-aligned.But I want to display the text centered on small displays.

Currently I found a solution using the d-none and d-block classes. But it is the same content in the columns which is loaded twice.

Is there a better solution?

```
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 text-center">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-left d-none d-md-block">
            <p>Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 d-md-none text-center">
            <p>Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be done easily with the help of default bootstrap classes like this

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 text-center">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 text-center text-md-left">
            <p>Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```